# Bindings creation order - Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, binding

When a function is called and the scope is constructed, in which order bindings are created? Is arguments binding created first? Followed by the bindings with each formal parameter as identifier and corresponding arguments as values.

something like this

```
const fnObj = {
    formalParams: ["name", "age", "occupation"]
};
        
const fnScope = {
    arguments: ["alice", 20, "student"],
    name: "alice",
    age: 20,
    occupation: "student"
};
```

Also what does the process of unpacking arguments into bindings look like?

```
function processArguments(fnObj, fnScope) {
    fnObj.formalParameters.forEach((param, i) => {
        fnScope[param] = fnScope.arguments[i];
    });
    return fnScope;
} //is it a right guess?
```

Comment: In modern JavaScript, the arguments have their own scope, which "surrounds" the scope of the function body. The argument scope is of necessity created first and populated left-to-right with actual parameter values.

Comment: Two scopes get created when a function is called? One for the arguments and other for function declarations? And the latter is an extension of the former?

Comment: Not an "extension" exactly, it's one scope nested inside another, just like the scope of a surrounding function or the scope of a `for` loop block with `let` and `const` declarations is "inside" another block. The arguments need their own scope because of the way parameter default values work.